# Python LinkedIn Search API 403 error

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am trying to get public profiles of people who work in company X to get their title, id, and connection. How do I properly use the Search API so I do not get 403 Forbidden error?

```
from linkedin import linkedin

CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXX'
USER_TOKEN = 'XXX'
USER_SECRET = 'XXX'

RETURN_URL = ''

auth = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET,
                                RETURN_URL,
                                permissions=linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

app = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(auth)


mm=app.search_profile(selectors=[{'people': ['headline','id','num-connections',]}], params={'keywords': 'microsoft'})
print mm
```

So this code gives me a error

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   30      
    search_profile  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\linkedin\linkedin.py  194     
    raise_for_error C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\linkedin\utils.py 65      
LinkedInForbiddenError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden: Access to people search denied.
```

Was the search API updated so search cannot be accessed. I do not want to use the normal search and copy paste everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears LinkedIn has a vetted process for developer access

http://developer-programs.linkedin.com/forum/error-403-client-error-forbidden-unknown-error

and you might have call customer service and agree to a TOS

http://community.linkedin.com/questions/116784/how-can-i-get-vetted-api-access-to-use-the-people.html

Another option would be to try using selenium to get the data http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Python bindings can be found here:https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/