# How to get a user public profile information in search_profile with username in linkedin?

Tags: python-2.7

from linkedin

```
import linkedin

CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXX'

CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXX'

USER_TOKEN = 'XXX'

USER_SECRET = 'XXX'

RETURN_URL ="http://localhost:8000"


auth = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, RETURN_URL,permissions=linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

app = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(auth)

profiles = app.search_profile(selectors=[{'people': ['first-name', 'last-name']}], params={'keywords': 'Ramya'})
```

I want to get the all the public profile information of Users Ramya
I tried like this i got error like shown below

```
LinkedInError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(first-name,last-name))?keywords=Ramya: Unknown Error
```

My Question is ,

How to get the all the public profile information of profile names of  Ramya
 And how to pass the params to search_profile

Comment: [HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) means 'forbidden', see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174780/python-linkedin-search-api-403-error) which has the same error.